# string splited by comma using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-analytics

How can I split a string by comma  using oracle sql?
Here I have a column which has values like below

```
123Lcq
Lf32i
jkp32m
```

I want to split it by comma

```
1,2,3,L,c,q
L,f,3,2,i
j,k,p,3,2,m
```

Comment: Does your data have multi-line strings?

Comment: Ronnie: you posted a related question yesterday. After you received answers, you posted the following comment:   "Thank you so much, it is the most amazing code I have ever seen. Amazing Oracle function. But what a shame I am using Netezza as my database. – Ronnie Lu 18 hours ago."  In a follow-up comment I asked you why that question was tagged "Oracle" if you don't use Oracle. Now I see you posted this question ALSO tagged as "oracle."    Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [regexp_replace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
SELECT substr(regexp_replace(mycol, '(.)', ',\1'), 2)
FROM   mytable
```

The regular expression finds every character, and those matching characters are then all prefixed with commas. Finally a simple `substr` is used to eliminate the first comma.

Note that trimming commas could be an alternative to `substr`, but the behaviour is different when the original value already has commas at the end of the string: when trimming, you also trim away these original commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    rtrim(regexp_replace(text, '(.)', '\1,'), ',') result
FROM (
    SELECT '123Lcq' text FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Lf32i'  text FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'jkp32m' text FROM dual)
```